# SVG IMAGE clip-path does not want move 40% to the right

Tags: css, svg, positioning, clip-path

How to move SVG clip-path 40% to the right ?

https://jsfiddle.net/vtgmsyg0/

My nested "svg" is not responding to specified for it "x coordinate" of value 40%...

I used nested SVG for this...

```
<svg width="120%" height="855">
  <svg width="900px" height="855px"  x="40%" y="10">
      <clipPath id="uniqueId" >
      <path transform="translate(0,664.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
      fill="#000000" stroke="none"d="M23 6616 c32 -51 1686 -2932 1691 -2946 4 -11 -57 -52 -226 -150
      -127 -75 -231 -139 -232 -142 -2 -11 1959 -3368 1967 -3368 5 0 505 288 1112
      640 607 352 1107 640 1112 640 4 0 37 -50 72 -110 l64 -110 47 27 c26 16 626
      368 1334 783 922 541 1285 759 1283 770 -3 8 -320 562 -706 1230 -387 668
      -703 1219 -704 1223 -2 8 550 327 2073 1198 l575 329 -4100 -1 c-2255 0 -4387
      2 -4738 4 l-638 5 14 -22z"/>
      </clipPath>
</svg>
</svg>
```

Comment: "x" has no effect on an SVG as a whole....it's an **element** attribute. - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/x You'd probably be better off changing the `viewbox`. You do have one of those...right?

Comment: I noticed that if you remove clipPath id="uniqueId" form HTML --> then x=40% works, but, of course, I want to include clip-path --> that's the whole point

Answer (score 0):

Change the X value in the `translate()` component of the `transform` attribute.  To move it left, make it a negative value.  40% of 900 is 360 so the following should be about right:

```
transform="translate(-360, 664.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
```

```css
body {
      overflow-x:hidden;
}


.mega {
    position:absolute;
    width:120%;
    height:100%;
    clip-path: url("#uniqueId");
    overflow-x:hidden;

    }
```

```html
<!-- This is the video used for SVG clipping -->

<video autoplay="" loop="" class="mega">
        <source src="https://gekos.pl/wp-content/themes/gekos/video/slider.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="https://gekos.pl/wp-content/themes/gekos/video/slider.ogg" type="video/ogg">
        <source src="https://gekos.pl/wp-content/themes/gekos/video/slider.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>



<!-- Code below is where I am applying clipping the the video, my nested "svg" is not responding to specified for 
it "x coordinate" of value 40% -->
        
<svg width="120%" height="855">
  <svg width="900px" height="855px">
      <clipPath id="uniqueId" >
      <path transform="translate(-360, 664.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)"
      fill="#000000" stroke="none"d="M23 6616 c32 -51 1686 -2932 1691 -2946 4 -11 -57 -52 -226 -150
      -127 -75 -231 -139 -232 -142 -2 -11 1959 -3368 1967 -3368 5 0 505 288 1112
      640 607 352 1107 640 1112 640 4 0 37 -50 72 -110 l64 -110 47 27 c26 16 626
      368 1334 783 922 541 1285 759 1283 770 -3 8 -320 562 -706 1230 -387 668
      -703 1219 -704 1223 -2 8 550 327 2073 1198 l575 329 -4100 -1 c-2255 0 -4387
      2 -4738 4 l-638 5 14 -22z"/>
      </clipPath>
</svg>
</svg>
```